# QGIS and QField show different behaviour regarding a Value Relation with Filter Expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sql, qfield

I added a **Value Relation** Widget in the *Attributes Form* of a shapefile in order to generate a drop-down menu that is supposed to make fieldwork more efficient. The idea is to have an **optional** filter that limits the options in this drop-down.

More specifically, I have a first drop-down in which I can select plant families. When a plant family is selected, I want to limit the options in the second drop-down (Genus) to the genera that are part of this plant family.

I have very limited experience with SQL, so this might be complete nonsense. But the following filter expression appears to work in QGIS desktop:

```
"Family" = current_value( 'Family' ) OR
current_value( 'Family' ) IS NULL
```

When no *Family* is set, all the options for *Genus* are available. When I select a *Family*, the options in *Genus* are limited to genera that are part of this family.

Now comes the problem:
When I export the project to **QField**, the filter no longer works. In QField, I can select any *Genus* at any time (independent of the *Family* that I have or have not selected previously); moreover it appears that selecting a *Genus* can even reset the *Family* value.

Here some screenshots of desktop and mobile version of the project. In both cases I selected *Aquifoliaceae* as the *Family* which should limit the *Genus* options to *Ilex* in this example. On the mobile device, the options were not limited and selecting *Acacia*, for example, did reset the *Family* to *NULL*. Subsequently, I selected the *Family* again, with no effect on the *Genus*.

[image: QGIS Desktop (I tried with several versions): When selecting the Family Aquifoliaceae, the options in Genus are correctly limited to Ilex (the only Genus in the list that belongs into this Family)]

[image: QField app (current PlayStore version): I can select other genera, such as Acacia even when Aquifoliaceae is set in the Family drop-down. Selecting a Genus that doesn't fit will reset the Family to NULL. Subsequently, I can again select the Family (which I did here) with no effect on the Genus.]

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Edit: I changed some plant family entries and exported the project again. Now the selection of a *Family* limits the *Genus* options, but the *Genus* doesn't limit the *Epithet* options. So basically, the problem moved to another level. I'm not sure what causes that issue but I suspect it is a bug in QField?

Comment: Is it possible that the issue occurs due to my smartphone having too little computational power?